# Proving image of compact set via upper semicontinuous set-valued map is compact

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, calculus-of-variations

Let $F:X\to2^Y$ be a set-valued map from a metric space to the subsets of another metric space. We say it is *upper semi-continuous* if for every $\epsilon$ and every $x_0\in X$ there exists $\delta$ such that $d(x,x_0)<\delta\implies F(x)\subseteq B(F(x_0),\epsilon)=\bigcup_{t\in F(x_0)}B(t,\epsilon)$.

My teacher introduced that, and, assuming by "image of a set via $F$" he meant:

$$F(A)=\bigcup_{t\in A}F(t),$$

from the way he put it, it seems the following theorem should be true.

> **Theorem**
>
> If $F:X\to2^Y$ is upper semi-continuous, then $F(K)$ is compact for all compact sets $K\subseteq X$.

I googled for a proof, and was unable to find one. I cannot think of one myself. How do I prove this theorem?

Note: For the purposes the course uses this for, $F$ can be assumed to be compact and convex-valued, and $X,Y$ can be assumed to be $\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m$, or even $n=m=1$, if needed.

**Update**

Comment by @user254665:

> Counter-example :If $Y$ is not compact and $X$ is not empty and $F(x)=Y$ for every $x\in x$...... BTW your assumption about the meaning of the image of a set is correct.

In effect, readig the notes more carefully, I find:

> Allora, sotto quese due condizioni, cioè la semicontinuità superiore e la compattezza, vale quella bella cosa, che l'immagine di un compatto è un compatto. E questaamm è la proprietà fondamentale che hanno queste mappe.

That is:

> Then, under these two conditions, that is upper semicontinuity and compactness, that nice thing holds, that the image of a compact set is a compact set. And this, uuh, is the fundamental properties that these maps have.

So it seems he actually stated the following:

> Let $f$ be USC *and compact-valued*. Then $F(K)$ is compact whenever $K$ is.

Can we prove this?

Comment: Counter-example :If $Y$ is not compact and  $X$ is not empty and  $F(x)=Y$ for every $x\in X.$..... BTW your assumption about the meaning of the image of a set is correct.

Comment: @user254665 see update.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll think about this Q.

Answer (score 0):

Please see Proposition 3, page 42 of the following book:

*Aubin, Jean-Pierre; Cellina, Arrigo*, Differential inclusions. Set-valued maps and viability theory, Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften, 264. Berlin etc.: Springer-Verlag. XIII, 342 p. DM 118.00; {$} 44.10 (1984). [ZBL0538.34007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0538.34007).