# Is an upper semicontinuous correspondence weakly measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, set-valued-analysis

**Definition 1**

Let $F:X\to2^Y$ be a set-valued map from a metric space to the subsets of another metric space. We say it is *upper semi-continuous* (USC) if for every $\epsilon$ and every $x_0\in X$ there exists $\delta$ such that $d(x,x_0)<\delta\implies F(x)\subseteq B(F(x_0),\epsilon)=\bigcup_{t\in F(x_0)}B(t,\epsilon)$.

**Definition 2**

$F:X\to2^Y$ with the properties above (except semicontinuity) is *weakly measurable* (WM) if the preimage of an open set is Borel, that is, if $V$ open implies $\{x:F(x)\cap V\neq\varnothing\}$ is Borel.

**Context**

The [Kuratowski-Ryll-Nardzewski theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896232/selection-problem-how-to-solve) works for WM functions. I need to apply it to a USC function (which is also convex-compact-valued, if it may be of interest) to construct a selection for a set function originating in a control problem, as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896232/selection-problem-how-to-solve). So I would need the implication $USC\implies WM$.

**Question**

> Is a USC correspondence necessarily WM?