# $(z_1,\dotsc,z_n)$ is a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n,0}$: why?

Tags: ring-theory, complex-geometry, holomorphic-functions, germs

I am studying the preliminary part of a course in Complex Geometry, and it deals with analytic sets and holomorphic functions, at the germ level. At some point, it says that the ideals $I_k:=(z_1,\dotsc,z_k)\leq\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n,0}$ (which is the ring of germs of holomorphic functions at 0 in $\mathbb{C}^n$) are all prime in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n,0}$. I googled, maybe not too smartly, but I found nothing. I tried to prove this myself, but I got stuck at some point. How would I go about proving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MickG the self-answerer is back :). This time, I was asking a genuine question, I was showing my work… and I finished the proof! So here is what I typed in the question box before moving it here.

Here is what I did. Suppose $fg\in I$. We must show $f\in I\vee g\in I$. $fg$ is a germ of a holomorphic function, hence we can write it as a "multivariate power series", and being in $I$ it has the form:

$$fg=\sum a_{i_1,\dotsc,i_m}z_{i_1}^{m_1}z_{i_m}^{m_m},$$

where $i_i\leq k$ for all $i$ and the $a_{i_1,\dotsc,i_m}$ are holomorphic functions. I guess this leads me pretty much nowhere. I mean, I somehow thought I could reduce the $a_{i_1,\dotsc,i_k}$ to being constant, but I guess I cannot. The only thing I seem[ed] to be able to tell is that $fg$ cannot have a known term, that is, all the terms in its power series must contain at least a coordinate function with a strictly positive exponent. Anyways, in my mistake, I expanded $f,g$ as power serieses and split them into $f_1+f_2+f_3$ where $f_1$ only had terms of the form $cz_{i_1}^{m_1}\dots z_{i_m}^{m_m}$ with $i_i\leq k$, $f_2$ only had terms of the form $cz_{i_1}^{m_1}\dots z_{i_m}^{m_m}$ with $i_i>k$ plus maybe a constant term, and $f_3$ had mixed terms. Now then I had:

$fg=(f_1+f_2+f_3)(g_1+g_2+g_3)=f_1g_1+f_1g_2+f_1g_3+f_2g_1+f_2g_2+f_2g_3+f_3g_1+f_3g_2+f_3g_3\equiv_If_2g_2+f_2g_3+f_3g_2+f_3g_3,$$

since $f_1,g_1\in I$ for sure. Then again, looking at it, $f_3,g_3$ can also be written in the form given for $fg$, since they only contain mixed terms: for each term, one separates the terms with the coordinate functions with index less than $k$ and puts the rest as a holomorphic function, so that all those terms are in $I$. So in the end:

$fg\equiv_If_2g_2.$$

$fg\in I$, hence $f_2g_2\in I$, but that doesn't contain any $z_i$ with $i\leq k$ with a strictly positive exponent, so none of its terms can be in $I$, hence to be i $I$ it must be zero. But then $f_2=0\vee g_2=0$, and this means, respectively, $f\in I\vee g\in I$. Whohoo, I thought I hadn't done it, and I just finished it! :)

So this is the last item of my "Share your knowledge, Q&A style!" tetralogy (or maybe pentalogy), the others being about [the Spectral Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453960/proof-of-spectral-theorem), [Weak Compactness of Closed Unit Balls in Hilbert Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462269/proving-the-closed-unit-ball-of-a-hilbert-space-is-weakly-sequentially-compact), and [the Fundamental Theorem of Integral Calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702423/proof-of-fundamental-theorem-of-integral-calculus) (and perhaps [the Kuratowski-Ryll Nardzewski theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896232/selection-problem-how-to-solve), though I'm not sure I used the

> **Answer your own question** - [share your knowledge, Q&A style](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)"

checkbox for this last cited post).